# Change Superclass of Subclass

Tags: matlab, oop

In Matlab I have the following classes:

```
car
plane
controller < car
```

Controller is a subclass of car and has properties that a normal car object does not have.

I now want to be able to create a `controller` object that is dynamically derived from `car` **or** `plane`. I kind of want something like `controller < car OR plane`.
Is it somehow possible to do this? If controller would be child of car **and** plane, it would always have all properties and methods from car and plane.

Is something like that even recommended or how should one tackle this issue? Or should I create two different classes and just call the one I need?

```
controllerCar < car
controllerPlane < plane
```

Comment: What benefit are you trying to gain by using some "car or plane" structure?

Comment: Benefit compared to what? I'd simply like to have only one controller class, otherwise I'd need to check for two classes in my code and not for one. (I am new to OOP, so it's likely that I misunderstand something about the usage of classes.)

Comment: Compared to "car and plane". If you want the controller object to inherit methods from car and plane then it should be a subclass of both. If you simply want a controller to reference a car or plane object then (you might want to make it a handle first) simply pass a vehicle object into the constructor of your controller and have it stored as a property.

Comment: Ah, that's a good idea! I am going to store the vehicle object as a property. :)

Comment: Seems like the more appropriate thing to do. As I say, depending on your usage, make the vehicle a handle class. Otherwise you're only passing an *instance* of the class as a property of the controller, not a reference to it. Meaning changing the `car` object externally won't change the car object within the controller.